# How to get the uploaded file names using AWS CDK BucketDeployment?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk

Background context:

I am using AWS CDK to create a S3 bucket and upload a file locally, So Inside the `BucketA`, I have a Object with key`text1.txt`.

I am trying to use `CfnOutput` to output the Object I upload in the CDK. It should be `text1.txt`, Is there a way to retrieve the object key i just upload?

Here is how I create bucket and upload `text1.txt` object:

```js
const bucketA = new Bucket(this, 'S3Bucket', {
  accessControl: BucketAccessControl.BUCKET_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL,
  blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ACLS,
  bucketName: `bucketA`,
  enforceSSL: true,
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
});

const uploadObject = new s3Deployment.BucketDeployment(
  this,
  `text1`,
  {
    sources: [s3Deployment.Source.asset(VALID_METADATA_PATH)],
    destinationBucket: bucketA,
    retainOnDelete: false,
    role: deploymentRole
  }
);
```

Here is what I tried:

```js
new CfnOutput(this, 'fileKey', {
    value: Fn.select(0, uploadObject.objectKeys)
});
```

- I am using [bucket deployment construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment.html#objectkeys)

However, when I check the output, it does not output the value I want,(`text1.txt`), rather it output something like:

```
this:cdk.out/asset.{315...a lot of numbers }.zip
```

When I inspect this `asset.{315...a lot of numbers }` locally in the cdk.out folder, I could see the `text1.txt` file inside `asset.{315...a lot of numbers }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

When using `aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment` there are 3 options how to pass source assets:

1. `Source.asset` and path to `.zip` file that contains all assets you want to upload.
2. `Source.asset` and path to directory with assets you want to upload.
3. `Source.data`/`Source.jsonData`/`Source.yamlData` will require to provide content of a file to upload.

All options except ***#1*** will be packed as `.zip` file eventually and sent to S3 where they get unpacked back. That's why you always see zip files in `uploadObject.objectKeys`.
Here is what [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment.html#objectkeys) is saying:

> This can be useful when using BucketDeployment with extract set to false and you need to reference the object key that resides in the bucket for that zip source file somewhere else in your CDK application, such as in a CFN output.

As you can see it will give you zipped source assets file name. You can try just read local file system in order to get desired output:

```js
fs.readdir(VALID_METADATA_PATH, {withFileTypes: true}, (err, files) => {
   files.forEach((file) => {
      new CfnOutput(this, `fileKey${i++}`, {
         value: file.name
      });
   });
});
```

---

Try running this code, it seems that variable name is wrong:

```
// Output the key of the uploaded object
new CfnOutput(this, 'fileKey', {
  value: Fn.select(0, uploadObject.objectKeys)
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I did use Fn.select(0, uploadObject.objectKeys), but forget to paste the correct object name when post the question, just updated the question.

Comment: Updated my response, looks like you need to read file manes from  s3 bucket or your local directory which is simpler

Comment: Thanks for explanation,  It confirm what I saw in the documentation, I thought there might be a way to get file name in S3 bucket deployment. 
I think I am satisfy with the read file from local directory. It is good enough!